# Writing to a new log file each day with TraceSource

Tags: c#

I am using a logger in my application to write to files. The source, switch and listeners have been defined in the app.config file as follows:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="LoggerApp" switchName="sourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="myListener.log" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="sourceSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Inside, my .cs code, I use the logger as follows:

```
private static TraceSource logger = new TraceSource("LoggerApp");
logger.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "{0} : Started the application", DateTime.Now);
```

What would I have to do to create a new log file each day instead of writing to the same log file every time?

Comment: some loggers support this out of the box (e.g.log4net) - you might want to consider that instead of trace logging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would I have to do to create a new log file each day instead of writing to the same log file every time?

You'd have to make your own [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) instead of using `TextWriterTraceListener`.  This would allow your `TraceListener` implementation to change log files daily, or do any other custom behavior you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try use:

<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="LoggerApp" switchName="sourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="myListener-{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}.log" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="sourceSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: This did not work for me: initializeData="myListener-{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}.log"

Comment: initializeData="myListener-{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}.log" in the config did not work for me. It threw a NotSupportedException with the message of 'The given path's format is not supported'